# How to get reference to 100 TextView in Android

Tags: android

I have 100 texView,with Id textView1,textView2,.........textView100.
Is there any way I can get reference to each of one in Loop ??

I'm trying below, but findViewById takes int.

```
TextView[] array=new TextView[100];
for(int i=1;i<101;i++)
array[i] = (TextView)findViewById( "R.Id.textView"+i);
```

Comment: If you have 100 variables with sequential numbers in their names, it's nearly certain you wanted an array, not separate variables, to begin with. Refactor them away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Resources.getIdentifier` should do what you need:

```
array[i] = (TextView) findViewById( Resources.getIdentifier("textView" + i, "id", getPackageName()) );
```